# Power Query if statement else with combined answer

Tags: excel, powerquery

Below you can find my if-Statement.
It's working without, any problems beside the last if-Statement.
In the last Statement, I want to combine the first two letters from one column plus "999999999999".
So the result should look like TQ999999999999.
At the moment, I'm getting an error as a result.

Do you have any tips, why I'm getting an error.

```
if [Column1]="2" then Text.Start([Column2],2)&999999999999 else 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put quotes around the 999999999